# c# Override a dependency property of an system control

Tags: c#, properties, overriding

Hi I have read through some of the relevant questions in stackoverflow but still can't figure out how to solve my questions:

I need to creat a CheckableGroupBox control which is same as GroupBox but has a checkbox in the header. And it has the following requirement:

1. The original GroupBox has a Header property that is of Object type, I need to limit this property in the CheckableGroupBox to be string only.
2. Users can change the header's text (the checkbox's text) by calling myCheckableGroupBox.Header="some text here".

I wrote the below code to serve these proposes:

```
public class CheckableGroupBox : System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox
{
    //override the default header property
    private static void OnHeaderChangedCallback(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckableGroupBox me = o as CheckableGroupBox;
        me.labHeader.Content = e.NewValue.ToString();        
    }

    public CheckableGroupBox() : base()
    {
        //setup the header of the group box

        //create the stack panel, add the checkbox and the label
        System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel sp = new System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel();
        sp.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal;
        this.chkHeader = new System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox();
        sp.Children.Add(this.chkHeader);
        sp.Children.Add(this.labHeader);

        //set the header to be the stack panel.
        this.Header = sp;

        //override the default HeaderProperty
        CheckableGroupBox.HeaderProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(object), 
            new PropertyMetadata("", OnHeaderChangedCallback)
            );
    }
```

}

However, the code doesn't work. When I add a CheckableGroupBox(in the design view) to a window, it prompts:

Cannot create an instance of "CheckableGroupBox", Object' type must derive from DependencyObject.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
   System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox.HeaderProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(CheckableGroupBox), 
            new PropertyMetadata("", OnHeaderChangedCallback)
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[CommonDependencyProperty]
public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(typeof (Control), (PropertyMetadata) new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((object) SystemFonts.MessageFontSize, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits));
```